# Looping through a pattern for use in a bash find command

Tags: regex, bash, loops, find, substitution

I'm trying to write a simple bash script to look through a directory and delete all versions of a file (except the latest 2) that match a pattern.  This command works great:

```
find . -type f -name 'a.*.log' -printf '%T@\t%p\n' \
  | sort -t $'\t' -g \
  | head -n -2 \
  | cut -d $'\t' -f 2- \
  | xargs rm -f
```

This will take the following files: a.1.log, a.2.log, and a.3.log, and delete a.1.log (assuming it's the oldest by timestamp).  The version portion of the filename is a hash, so not numerically in order (I changed it for simplicity).

So, what I want to do is loop through a set of different patterns and feed each one to the find command above.  I've simplified the script for this example to look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES="a.*.log
b.*.log
c.*.log"

for f in $FILES
do
    echo "Processing $f"
    find . -type f -name "$f"
done
```

The directory I'm running this from has these files:

```
a.1.log, a.2.log, a.3.log, b.1.log, b.2.log, b.3.log, c.1.log, c.2.log, c.3.log
```

The output I get from the above script is:

```
Processing a.1.log
./a.1.log
Processing a.2.log
./a.2.log
Processing a.3.log
./a.3.log
Processing b.1.log
./b.1.log
Processing b.2.log
./b.2.log
Processing b.3.log
./b.3.log
Processing c.1.log
./c.1.log
Processing c.2.log
./c.2.log
Processing c.3.log
./c.3.log
```

What I need is for the output to look like this:

```
Processing a.*.log
./a.1.log
./a.2.log
./a.3.log
Processing b.*.log
./b.1.log
./b.2.log
./b.3.log
Processing c.*.log
./c.1.log
./c.2.log
./c.3.log
```

I've tried using an array instead of looping through a string, escaping the file patterns, using single vs double quotes in the find, etc... But I can't get it to simply substitute the pattern into the find.  If I run the finds individually by hand, it gives me the output I'm looking for:

```
$ find . -type f -name "a.*.log"
./a.1.log
./a.2.log
./a.3.log
$ find . -type f -name "b.*.log"
./b.1.log
./b.2.log
./b.3.log
$ find . -type f -name "c.*.log"
./c.1.log
./c.2.log
./c.3.log
```

I can't find any examples of someone looping through a collection of patterns and substituting them into a command.  Any help would be awesome.

Thanks.

Comment: Note that it's quite legal for a filename to contain a literal newline; consequently, NUL-delimited streams are safer than newline-delimited ones.

Comment: Similarly, when `xargs` isn't passed `-0` or `-d`, it parses whitespace -- if you have `c. foo bar.log`, it'll try to delete files `c.`, `foo`, and `bar.log`.

Comment: BTW -- was it intentional that you rolled back my formatting changes? Formatting your code as text (on one line, without syntax highlighting or code formatting) hinders its readability significantly.

Comment: BTW, if you want to display data without code formatting, four-space indents are appropriate for that -- just precede the block with `<!-- language: none -->` to disable syntax highlighting.

Comment: Sorry about the formatting.  I had put all of the shell output in as code and it was syntax highlighting where it shouldn't have.  I was in the middle of fixing it.  I didn't expect responses so quickly.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on xargs.  The files won't have whitespace in them, but I'll fix it anyway.  That command works for what I need, it's the looping through the patterns and feeding them into the find command that isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem you encounter is that without quotes variable is split but also file globbing occurs, this can be avoided using shell option noglob `set -f`, or using an array and using double quotes :

```
files=( 'a.*.log' 'b.*.log' 'c.*.log' )

for f in "${files[@]}"; do
...
```

Comment: Much better to use an array -- as you show here -- than to use `set -f`.

Comment: Using this resulted in no output.  It doesn't even run the echo for me.

Comment: @fudgit, if your shell is really bash (not `/bin/sh`), that's unlikely. See https://ideone.com/L59tSd for an online interpreter showing a loop over the glob expressions in question operating correctly.

Comment: My apologies.  I had a typo in my script.  That does work.  And thank you for the quick response and the reference to ideone.com.  That's a nice tool.